# How to set the state, control, and parameter options in a dimensioned Dymos problems?

Tags: openmdao

I have an ODE given in the form [image: a1] where x, u, and d are vectors (e.g. [image: a2]) . I've formulated this system in OpenMDAO/Dymos using dimensioned inputs and outputs

```
self.add_input('x',shape(num_nodes,Nx))
```

for Nx states. See: https://openmdao.github.io/dymos/getting_started/defining_odes.html?highlight=dimensioned#dimensioned-inputs-and-outputs

My ODE and trajectory works well, however, I'm interested in having some information clarified:

(1) I see that when adding states, inputs, and parameters, I can supply unique box constraints via `upper` and `lower` (https://openmdao.github.io/dymos/features/phases/constraints.html?highlight=dimensioned#path-constraints). For example, state 1 can have bounds [0,1] while state 2 has bounds [-1,5]. My question is, does suppling `ref` and `ref0` information work in this same way? I tested this (e.g. `ref0 = [0,-1]`), but I can't tell if it is actually doing anything?

(2) Can you specify the units of specific elements of the dimensioned problems? For example, state 1 is a temperature and state 2 in a voltage. It does not look like I can simply do:

```
self.add_input('x',shape=(num_nodes,2),units=['K','V'])
```

because this returns an error.

(3) Can you specify different optimization properties for individual pieces in the state, input, and dimension vectors? For example, say I want to optimize input 1 (`opt=True`) but not input 2 (`opt=False`). Ideally, I would expect

```
phase.add_parameter('u',opt=[True,False])
```

but this returns an error.

If this functionality is possible, could you direct me to where I could find more information. I have gone through the Dymos documentation but could not find much on the topic.

Comment: Originally we decided not to support array-based scaling, in large part because Michael Ross et al make a convincing argument that it's not mathematically correct.  See the section entitled "Fallacy of Discrete Scaling" in their paper "Scaling and Balancing for High-Performance Computation of
Optimal Controls" here:  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.11073.pdf

If you feel this would be really important and want to disregard Ross' advice, I wouldn't be completely opposed to adding in the capability.


Scaling for each index of an array valued state or control should already work, will test.

Comment: I think that the scaling that Mike Ross argued against was slightly different. That was variable scaling along the `num_nodes` axis, which he makes a convincing argument is bad. I believe in this case, the variable scaling would be along the "primary" axis of the vector state (i.e. along the axis that you would split a vector state up into multiple scalar states). There is nothing mathematically wrong with this that I can see, and It seems to partially work as of V1.3 for ref/ref0. it does not work for upper/lower though. That can get addressed in the bug that is noted in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In general OpenMDAO You can have vector valued ref/ref0 for design variables. Dymos should, in theory, also support this. You can give a ref/ref0 the same size as your state and then Dymos will extend it out to the full `num_nodes` size for you. Unfortunately, as of Dymos V 1.30 it looks like this doesn't quite work. We've [logged that bug here](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/dymos/issues/692), and it should be fixed by V1.4.
2. OpenMDAO does not allow mixed units within arrays. This was an intentional design choice related to details about how unit conversions are handled and how to keep them efficient (both in terms of memory and compute usage). Because OpenMDAO doesn't allow it, Dymos can't.

So you either need to split the state up into multiple variables, or work in nondimentional quantities.

3. For parameters and controls this is fairly strait forward via OpenMDAO's APIs. If you want finer grained index control, just set opt=False for all of them. Dymos will expose them as inputs at the top of the phase/trajectory for you (you can use the N2 to find them). Then you can call the native OpenMDAO API [`add_design_var`](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/dymos/issues/692) on those phase/trajectory level inputs with whatever indecies you want.

Doing this for states isn't a great idea. Without getting to far into the math... Dymos works really hard to keep a well defined (in the mathematical sense) optimization problem for you. For states that means carefully matching up the defect constraints with the design variables. You can't just turn off part of a state array without also addressing the corresponding defect constraints. Of course, if you mess with the defect constraints then you aren't getting valid physics any more. This is such a huge can of worms that you really just don't want to touch it.

Comment: Awesome. This is very helpful and thank you for opening that bug report. To clarify, for (3), I wouldn't want to remove states from the list of design variables. However, I may want some states with a fixed initial condition where others are free. It seems like that may still be 'okay'. But, based on what you both mentioned, it seems like the better approach would be to avoid the dimensioned problem and put some effort into reformulating my system as nondimensional.

Comment: If you have a vector valued state, then you can only control the `fix_intial` or `fix_final` setting for ALL sub-states in that array as a block. If you need finer control than that, then you should break the vector up into smaller variables. At least thats how it works as of V1.3

While we'd welcome a pull request that could update the functionality, I think we'd need some convincing that it wouldn't create a lot of potential headaches for users. Its hard enough to get the BCs right when you work with whole variables. Boolean Arrays would just make it that much harder.

Comment: Oh. Okay well that helps to settle our approach.  We'll have to break up each of the states   et al into their own variable. I'll save the headache of having to do that update. Thanks for clarifying!